# Alphvantage Intraday API has not been working for last few days, API is throwing back "Key Error: "Time Series (1min)'"

Tags: python-3.x, alpha-vantage

Have been trying to query intraday series, but the call is failing with the below error.

Can someone please help me resolve this error?

Code is really simple, just querying USG equity symbol for 1 min interval from API

data, meta_data = av_ts.get_intraday(symbol='USG',interval='1min', outputsize='full')

This is the error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-12-3e7fe1bd42d0> in <module>()
    ----> 1 data, meta_data = av_ts.get_intraday(symbol='USG',interval='1min', outputsize='full')

    c:\users\sampleuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\alpha_vantage\alphavantage.py in _format_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
        175             if 'json' in self.output_format.lower() or 'pandas' \
        176                     in self.output_format.lower():
    --> 177                 data = call_response[data_key]
        178                 if meta_data_key `enter code here`is not None:
        179                     meta_data = call_response[meta_data_key]

    KeyError: 'Time Series (1min)'
```

Comment: Sorry to bother all, i think this is because USG got delisted. Thank you anyway all.

Answer (score 1):

USG traded on April 18th, and on the 23rd, but not since then.

The API is having trouble offering 1-minute updates of an issue that doesn't trade.

Comment: Thanks J_H, noted. I am changing my codes to catch these errors as exceptions and log them.